# In Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS is it safe to ignore the existence of "root"?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, root

I'm not sure I'm even asking the question right, but basically what I'm wondering is whether it is safe to go about using the user that the install wizard had me create, and disregard the existence of a root user, or do I need to explicitly disable root login and/or do anything else.

Comment: Safe in what sense?

Comment: @Paul - good question, I'm not sure. Safe from some other user being able to log in as `root`, or from some program that I run when SSH'd in as a sudo user doing something that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu's default installation configuration is to set up a disabled root account (yet does exists). Disabled in a sense that it has no password set and PAM does not allow to authenticate without a password set. However, the user you've created during installation is included in the `sudo` group, so this user can get root privileges using `sudo`.

In terms of security it is a little bit safe to use a non-standard user name in a default installation apart from `root`, which is much easier to guess.

If you need to enable the `root` account, just do `sudo su -`, then `passwd` to set a password for `root`.

Answer (score 1):

The default Ubuntu installation does not allow a person to login anonymously as "root".
So "yes", you can ignore the "root" user, and use the `sudo` command prefix to perform operations that need superuser privileges.